# Using an array in a function error

Tags: python, function, numpy, typeerror, curve-fitting

When I run my code I receive the error "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'numpy.ufunc' and 'float'"

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sqrt,exp,log
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data1 = np.loadtxt('decay1.txt', float,skiprows=1)
t = data1[:,0]
n = data1[:,1]

data2 = np.loadtxt('decay2.txt', float,skiprows=1)
T = data2[:,0]
N = data2[:,1]

def Radio(n,t,tao,b):
    return (n*(exp**(-(t/tao)))) + b

guesses = (1,1,1)
guesses2 = (1,1,1)

(p0,p1,p2),cc = curve_fit(Radio,t,n,guesses)
(p02,p12,p22),cc2 = curve_fit(Radio,T,N,guesses2)

yfit = Radio(t,p0,p1,p2)
y2fit = Radio(T,p02,p12,p22)
```

I have to fit the function to the radioactive decay data, so tell me if I also messed up the code to fit a function to it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: with respect to your second question, I have not used `scipy.optimize`, but from the docs it looks right to me, with the exception that I think you switched the order of inputs between the function (`n,t`) and the curve fit (`t,n`)

Comment: I take that back, looks like there is a problem in the formulation.  Will edit my answer with description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.exp` is the exponential function and `**` is the power operator, so you're trying to raise a function definition to the power `(-(t/tao))`.  I think you wanted

```
def Radio(n,t,tao,b):
    return (n*(exp(-(t/tao)))) + b
```

With respect to the use of the optimization function, there are a couple of issues.  First, you are using `n` as both the parameter (inside the `Radio` method) and the dependent variable data (from the problem statement), which is confusing things.  I would change that to something like `a` (as is used in [the curve_fit doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit).  That's not really necessary, but helps readability.

Second, and more importantly, the function to be fit *must* have the independent variable (in this case, `t`) as the *first* argument.  I think what is happening to cause a flat fit is that you are actually fitting the curve `n->Radio(n)` (with all those other variables as parameters) instead of `t->Radio(t)`.

Comment: Oh wow! thanks a ton haha, how do I select this as the answer?

Comment: @BrandonSeedlessBananasMc-Wil updated with potential fix for the curve fit